# How to implement requiredUnless validator of vuelidate for checkboxes

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vuelidate

Using Vuelidate, since 'required' validator now considers boolean 'false' a valid value, you have to use 'sameAs' like `sameAs: sameAs( () => true )` to implement required validation for checkboxes. How to implement 'requiredUnless' validation for checkboxes using vuelidate where checkbox is only required to be checked if a property is not a certain value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

false is validate as valid so you need to change it to an empty string, I'll do this in watch:

```
    data() {
        return {
            email: '',
            age: null,
            password: '',
            confirmPassword: '',
            country: 'Malta', 
            hobbyInputs: [],
            terms: '',
            countries,                
        }
    },        
    validations: {
      terms: {
        required: requiredUnless(vm => {
          return vm.country === 'Malta'
        }),
      }
    },
    watch: {
      terms() {
        if (!this.terms) {
          this.terms = '';
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way validating with vuelidate. So I made method which toggles a css class by executing a method and pass $v object to it and only run validation when the value is not a chosen value.

```
 <div class="input inline" :class="{invalid: checkCountry($v)}">
```

The validator

```
 Validations: {
  terms: {
    sameAs: sameAs(vm => {
      if (!(vm.country === 'germany')) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
```

The method

```
methods: {
    checkCountry($v) {
      if (this.country === 'germany') {
        return false;
      } else {
        return $v.terms.$invalid;
      }
    }
```